# how to convert an image from BGR to LAB with opencv 2.4 python 2.7 and numpy

Tags: image-processing, opencv, numpy, python-2.7

I am working with opencv 2.4 and numpy. I would like to open an image and get all the information about it (8 bit - if its RGB-BGR etc) and also try to change the color space.
I have this code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    img =  cv2.imread('imL.png') 
    conv= cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
        cv2.imwrite('lab.png', conv )
```

When I open the file `lab.png` I get the image with different colors!
I check the value of BGR to LAB in: http://www.brucelindbloom.com/

For this I would like to know all the information about one image.

Answer (score 3):

That rigtht you will get a different image colour because imwrite() saves file in the format specified (PNG, JPEG 2000, and TIFF) single-channel or 3-channel (with ‘BGR’ channel order). images can be saved using this function. imwrite() doesn't know the format LAB to save image as it always expect the image in BGR. 
If the format, depth or channel order is different, use Mat::convertTo() , and cvtColor() to convert it before saving.

Comment: Thanks! i was guessing that  and i have tried also with the PIL library but it looks like it doesn't support LAB as well.
But also MAT::convertTo() looks avaliable just for c++ i didn't find any examples with python. Am I righ?

Comment: You can check out python equivalent of MAT::convertTo() cv.Convert(src, dst). It copies one array to another with optional scaling, which is performed first, and/or optional type conversion, performed after. Useful if you want the change 8U image to float or vis-versa.

Comment: I am afraid that it's not possible with opencv 2.4, as you can see you wrote cv.Convert(src, dst). Also googleing i didn't find in the documentation.
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#void Mat::convertTo(OutputArray m, int rtype, double alpha, double beta) const
Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 2):

Lab is another color space, like the BGR color space which is gained from cv2.imread(). It just like you convert temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius.
32 Fahrenheit and 0 Celsius is the same temperature but in different unit.

cv2.imwrite() dose not know if the values are in BGR color space or not. When it get a 3 dimension array, it assume that it is a BGR color space while your conv variable contains Lab color space. This is why your color of your image is changed.

For your information, Each layer of BGR color space contains blue, green and red colors while layers of Lab contains lightness (0-100), a* and b* respectively. For more information, please see "Lab color space" in Wikipedia.

Comment: i know what the lab color is.
My concern was about the matching of the value were not right.
I check the value of BGR to LAB in this website: http://www.brucelindbloom.com/
And they were different!
BTW i found out that you save the image as float32 and then you make the conversion to LAB the value match so i think the problem was that at the beginning the image was saved in uint8